# Passing string prop into styled component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to pass `btnName` into my styled component's css but it's not taking it in & rendering it. It's just blank/`' '`

```
    /* Content under the animation */
    content: ${(props) => props.btnName};
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white; /* Color of text - change if white or dark theme */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
`;
```

I've set `btnName` to `DEPOSIT` elsewhere. I was just wondering if how I would do this properly?

```
const IcingOffButton: React.FC<ButtonType> = ({
  btnName,
  isDisabled,
  onClick,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <IcingOff
        btnName={btnName}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        onClick={onClick}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

I've done something similar, not sure why it's not working with the string type?

```
const Base = styled.button<ButtonType>`
  margin: 10px; 
  position: relative;
  background: #303032; 
  border: 0.22rem solid #303032;
  border-radius: .75rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: ${(props) => props.isDisabled ? 'auto' : 'pointer'};
`
```

Comment: I don't think it is related to string-type prop. When you inspect the element on the browser, can you see the `content` css?

Comment: I can't see it in the `content` css. Very odd. It does show when I hard code a name though. Any ideas?